# How to use extra monitors as workspaces in Ubuntu mate 17.10

Tags: multiple-monitors, workspaces, mate

I just purchased a second monitor, and I want to be able to use it. The only issue is that the current system I have treats the new monitor as an extension of my laptop monitor. What I want is a way to have each monitor act as a workspace. I'll try to describe it. Say [x] is my laptop monitor, and {y} is my external monitor. I have 4 workspaces, 1,2,3,4. when I start out, it would look like [1],{2},3,4. When I do the keyboard shortcut to go right, it would change to 1,[2],{3},4, moving along the line. Is there any way to do what I've described? I'm on Ubuntu Mate 17.10. Cheers!

Comment: There are several references to Workspaces and monitors in the frame on the right of this page.  One of them includes this: [Two different workspaces for two monitors](https://askubuntu.com/q/654176/29012)

Comment: I already saw that one, and my issue is that Displays no longer has that option in 17.10.